# Trying to use reduce to sum properties from objects in an array: Undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects. Each object has a property "amount" with an integer value such as 30000. I want to sum them using reduce, but it returns undefined.

If I console.log() currentValue.amount it returns the values, no problem. I can't quite grasp why at the time of adding them it returns undefined.

```
let items = [
     { id: 0, name: "Food", amount: 30000 },
     { id: 1, name: "Insurance", amount: 25000 },
     { id: 2, name: "Rent", amount: 50000 }
   ]

    let total = items.reduce((a, b) => {
       console.log(b.amount); // 30000 (first loop)
       a + b.amount; // undefined
     }, 0);
     console.log(total);
```

My expected result, of course, is that it would sum the values and in the end the variable "total" will be assigned the sum of each object's amount property value.

EDIT: I forgot the return!

```
   let items = [
         { id: 0, name: "Food", amount: 30000 },
         { id: 1, name: "Insurance", amount: 25000 },
         { id: 2, name: "Rent", amount: 50000 }
       ]

   let total = items.reduce((a, b) => {
       console.log(b.amount); // 30000 (first loop)
       return a + b.amount; // 105000 OK
     }, 0);
     console.log(total);
```

Comment: return the accu.

Comment: You're missing a `return` statement. `a + b.amount` is being shouted into the void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` the accumulator.

```js
let items = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Food",
    amount: 30000
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Insurance",
    amount: 25000
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Rent",
    amount: 50000
  }
]

let total = items.reduce((a, b) => {
  return a + b.amount;
}, 0);
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `return`,

Reduce function must return something which will be then used as the first param of function in the next iteration.

```js
let items = [
     { id: 0, name: "Food", amount: 30000 },
     { id: 1, name: "Insurance", amount: 25000 },
     { id: 2, name: "Rent", amount: 50000 }
   ]

let total = items.reduce((a, b) => {
  return a + b.amount;
}, 0);
console.log(total);
```

Comment: SO stoooopid. Found out as soon as I had posted it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) works by returning the accumulator from the function. You've forgotten the `return` keyword in your second line.

```js
let items = [{id:0,name:"Food",amount:30000},{id:1,name:"Insurance",amount:25000},{id:2,name:"Rent",amount:50000}];

let total = items.reduce((a, b) => {
  console.log(b.amount); 
  return a + b.amount; 
}, 0);

console.log("Total:", total);
```

You could also use destructuring and the implicit return of arrow functions like so:

```js
let items = [{id:0,name:"Food",amount:30000},{id:1,name:"Insurance",amount:25000},{id:2,name:"Rent",amount:50000}];

let total = items.reduce((a, { amount: b }) => (console.log(b), a + b), 0);

console.log("Total:", total);
```